# Finding values that don't exist in a specific column in another table in SQL

Tags: sql, exists, not-exists

(First time posting so apologies if this is rubbish)

I have two tables I'm working from - for the sake of this question we'll use food pairings.

**TABLE A**

**Column A: FOOD TYPE -** Peas, Beef, Cake, Cheese
**Column B: Quantity -** 11, 9, 4, 6

**TABLE B**

**Column A: Food type -** Peas, Beef, Cake, Cheese
**Column B: Quantity -** 11, 9, 4, 6
**Column C: Goes well with -** Carrots, Cheese, Cheese, Peas

I need to find values that exist in Table A but are not specifically in the "GOES WELL WITH" column in Table B.  So in this case it would return beef.  I can't seem to use NOT EXISTS because beef does still appear in Table B (under FOOD TYPE).  Is there an amendment I can make to the code where it looks to see if a value exists in a specific column?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please tell us, which programming language you'd like to use. Perhaps add an appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you may simply use NOT IN then -

```
SELECT FOOD_TYPE
FROM TABLEA
WHERE FOOD_TYPE NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Goes_well_with
                        FROM TABLEB)
```

Comment: Ah, it was the distinct bit I was missing, thank you!

Comment: I don't think distinct will make any difference here in terms of values apart from performance perspective.

Comment: @SirJohnMcPoopingtonXVIIJr . . . The "distinct part" is superfluous and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this SQL Query:

```
select Table_A.FOOD_TYPE from Table_A 
left join Table_B on Table_A.FOOD_TYPE = Table_B.Goes_well_with
where Table_B.Goes_well_with is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You should show the `not exists` query.  It should look like this:

```
select a.FOOD_TYPE
from Table_A a
where not exists (select 1
                  from Table_B b
                  where a.FOOD_TYPE = b.Goes_well_with
                 );
```